# Calling Azure AD Preview from C# Causes RestSharp MissingMethodException, Works Fine in ISE

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, restsharp

I'm receiving an error of ""Method not found: 'RestSharp.IRestRequest RestSharp.RestRequest.AddQueryParameter(System.String, System.String)'." when using the AzureADPreview cmdlet from C# and a runspace invoke. The script works flawlessly in PowerShell ISE.

Here's the script:

```
Import-Module MSOnline
Import-Module AzureADPreview

Write-Host Creating credentials...
$adminUsername = "removed"
$adminPassword = "removed"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $adminPassword -AsPlainText -Force

# Attempt to get credentials object
$credentials = new-object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $adminUsername, $securePassword

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credentials

# Delete the non-enterprise apps.
Write-Host Deleting non-enterprise apps...
Get-AzureADApplication -ErrorAction Stop | Select ObjectId | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $_.ObjectId }

Return "Run completed without error."
```

This works perfectly from PowerShell ISE.

The C#, however, throws the error above at the Get-AzureADApplication line. Any ideas?

```
public static string GetScriptResultString(string scriptText)
{
    // Create Powershell runspace with access to MS Online.
    var initialState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    initialState.ImportPSModule(new[] { "MSOnline" }); // ensure we have access to Msol-Connect and so forth.
    initialState.UseFullLanguageModeInDebugger = true;
    initialState.LanguageMode = PSLanguageMode.FullLanguage;
    using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialState))
    {
        // Open the runspace.
        runspace.Open();

        // Invoke as necessary.
        var invoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
        invoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force");

        // Create a pipeline and feed it the script text.
        try
        {
            using (var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
            {
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

                // Return the script outputs as strings.
                pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

                // execute the script
                var results = pipeline.Invoke();

                // close the runspace
                runspace.Close();

                // Convert the script result into a single string
                var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var obj in results)
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
                }

                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.GetBaseException().Message;
            Debug.WriteLine($"GetScriptResultString(): Exception occurred: { msg }");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Specifically, the part failing in C# appears to be:

Get-AzureADApplication -ErrorAction Stop | Select ObjectId

Comment: It also works from the command prompt, fyi.

Comment: Typo: It's failing on Get-AzureADApplication, not the Select ObjectId portion.

Comment: This is not a RestSharp issue. It is someone using RestSharp and not including the library in their distribution. You should address your question to them.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I added a reference to https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/, then, in the PowerShell script, I added:

```
Add-Type -Path RestSharp.dll
```

**I have no idea why this works WITHOUT THIS CHANGE in PowerShell ISE, and from PowerShell directly.** The updated script looks as follows:

```
Import-Module MSOnline
Import-Module AzureADPreview

Add-Type -Path RestSharp.dll

Write-Host Creating credentials...
$adminUsername = "@@USERNAME@@"
$adminPassword = "@@PASSWORD@@"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $adminPassword -AsPlainText -Force

# Attempt to get credentials object
$credentials = new-object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $adminUsername, $securePassword

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credentials

# Note the list apps may not update immediately. Wait a minute or so before checking the app lists.

# Delete the non-enterprise apps.
Write-Host Deleting non-enterprise apps...
Get-AzureADApplication -ErrorAction Stop | Select ObjectId | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $_.ObjectId }

Return "Run completed without error."
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same exact error.Uninstalling the RestSharp.dll and Reinstalling the same from nuget and then closing and opening of visual studio2015 solve my issue.